# Diferenças entre Git e Mercurial

Tags: git, versionamento, mercurial

Quais as principais diferenças, vantagens e limitações desses dois sistemas de controle de versão distribuídos?

Se alguém tem experiência prática em *ambos* (eu por exemplo só conheço mais a fundo o Mercurial, e estou em dúvida se devo ou não me aprofundar no Git), eu também gostaria de saber se existe algum cenário ou caso de uso em que um apresenta vantagens em relação ao outro, ou se eles são essencialmente equivalentes.

Comment: Eu também tenho mais experiência com Mercurial, gosto mais dele, mas o Git está se tornando universal e isso tem peso. Eu acho que para a maioria das equipes um Mercurial ou até mesmo um SVN resolve bem e mais fácil que o Git, quase ninguém precisa de fato do que só o Git oferece mas parece que tem mais gente porque alguns tem vozes altas e há uma quantidade grande de adeptos porque há uma quantidade grande de adeptos. Eu fico nessa que sei que popularidade é *feature* mas não deveria ser motivo forte para decisão. O que eu sei sobre o Git é mais do leio. Só fiz o básico com ele.

Comment: Bom eu até poderia formatar uma resposta aqui mas para contemplar os tópicos requisitados a quantidade de informações seria grande, então vou esperar se alguém com mais tempo se habilita a fazer, de qualquer forma a uns anos atrás tive que começar a trabalhar com `DVCS` e um artigo que me ajudou bastante a entender e decidir o que usar foi esse http://pronus.eng.br/blog/http:/pronus.eng.br/blog/comparacao-entre-subversion-mercurial-e-git-parte-1

Answer (score 8):

## Resumo

### Git

O Git é a estrela ascendente dos controles de versão, ele foi desenvolvido pelo criador do Kernel do Linux e recentemente vem sendo largamente utilizado pela comunidade de desenvolvedores e startups.

O Git oferece um controle de versão diferente, o [Distributed Version Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control), ou simplesmente, controle de versão distribuído. Com esta forma de controle não existe um servidor central como no SVN por exemplo, que usa versão centralizada.

A comunidade diz que o Git é o controle de versão mais rápido do mercado. Dentre alguns que usam o Git podemos citar o Linux Kernel, Wine, Fedora, dentre outros, o GitHub se estabilizou como um grande controle de versões baseado em Git, provendo um belo front end para grandes projetos como Rails e Prototype, entretanto, o Git não é muito fácil de se aprender, sendo portanto, não muito recomendado para iniciantes no mundo de controle de versões.

### Mercurial

O Mercurial é outro controle de versão distribuído. Assim como o Git, ele foi desenvolvido para projetos de grande porte, muito além dos projetos simples de designers e desenvolvedores independentes, obviamente isso não significa que times pequenos não possam utilizá-lo, o Mercurial é extremamente rápido e os criadores focaram na performance como recurso mais importante.

Além de ser muito rápido e escalável, o Mercurial é mais simples que o Git, não existem tantas funções para aprender e as funções são similares a outros CVS’s, além de ele vir equipado com uma interface web e ter uma excelente documentação.

Como adicional, deixo um [link de um artigo](http://pronus.eng.br/blog/http:/pronus.eng.br/blog/comparacao-entre-subversion-mercurial-e-git-parte-1) falando um pouco sobre performance dos controles de versão citados acima.

Fonte: [QUAL O MELHOR CONTROLE DE VERSÃO? SUBVERSION/GIT/MERCURIAL](http://blog.vandersonguidi.com.br/utilidade-publica/qual-o-melhor-controle-de-versao-subversiongitmercurial)

Apesar ser ser um comparativo entre Subversion, Git e Mercurial, acredito que pode ajudar o autor da pergunta.

## Complexidade

A complexidade da ferramenta tem impacto direto na produtividade dos desenvolvedores e é o fator decisivo para o aprendizado e operação correto da ferramenta. Os critérios usados para medi-la foram o número de comandos e número de linhas dos textos de ajuda.

Embora não sejam perfeitos, são suficientes para apontar indícios a respeito da complexidade da ferramenta, além de serem imparciais e de fácil medição. Outras dimensões de complexidade das ferramentas serão abordadas em análises posteriores.
O detalhamento dos critérios e das premissas de comparação são apresentados a seguir:

1. Número de comandos. Todas as ferramentas possuem dezenas comandos e conhecê-los é um desafio para qualquer usuário.

Premissa: Quanto menor o número de comandos, mais fácil de conhecê-los.

Contra-argumento: Poderia haver um comando só com dezenas de opções e parâmetros, e isso não o tornaria mais simples. No entanto, o texto de ajuda deste comando ficaria mais extenso. Portanto, só o número de comandos não é suficiente, mas se combinado com a análise do número de linhas de ajuda dos comandos, volta a ficar relevante.

2. Números de linhas dos textos de ajuda. Todas as ferramentas textos de ajuda para seus comandos com objetivo de apresentar o funcionamento do comando e as opções disponíveis. Premissas:

   **a.**  O formato e a qualidade dos textos de ajuda das diferentes ferramentas sendo analisadas são equivalentes.

   **b.**  Os textos de ajuda contêm apenas o mínimo de contéudo necessário para descrever adequadamente os comandos.

   **c.**  Comandos mais complexos precisam de textos mais longos para serem descritos. Portanto, quanto menor o número de linhas do texto de ajuda necessário para explicar um comando, mais simples ele é.

### Número de Comandos

O Subversion possui ao todo 68 comandos diferentes, agrupados em categorias: `svn` para tarefas de controle de versão, `svnadmin` para manipulação e manutenção de repositórios, `svnlook` para exames do repositório em scripts de hook etc.

Subversion: 68 comandos diferentes (Alguns se repetem. Por exemplo, `help`)

- `svn`: 36 comandos
  add, blame, cat, changelist, checkout, cleanup, commit, copy, delete, diff, export, help, import, info, list, lock, log, merge, mergeinfo, mkdir, move, patch, propdel, propedit, propget, proplist, propset, relocate, resolve, resolved, revert, status, switch, unlock, update, upgrade
- `svnadmin`: 20 comandos
  crashtest, create, deltify, dump, help, hotcopy, list-dblogs, list-unused-dblogs, load, lslocks, lstxns, pack, recover, rmlocks, rmtxns, setlog, setrevprop, setuuid, upgrade, verify
- `svnlook`: 17 comandos
  author, cat, changed, date, diff, dirs-changed, filesize, help, history, info, lock, log, propget, proplist, tree, uuid, youngest
- `svnrdump`: 3 comandos
  dump, load, help
- `svndumpfilter`: 3 comandos
  exclude, include, help
- `svnsync`: 5 comandos
  initialize, synchronize, copy-revprops, info, help

O **Mercurial** possui 55 comandos no total (com fetch e rebase habilitados), podendo aumentar de acordo com o número de extensões habilitadas. Dezoito desses comandos são considerados básicos, apresentados ao se executar o comando `hg` sem nenhum subcomando ou parâmetro adicional. Não há uma subdivisão adicional dos comandos em uma classe administrativa ou para scripts como no Subversion, embora hajam comandos claramente voltados exatamente estes fins, como é o caso dos comandos `verify` e `identify` por exemplo.

**Mercurial: 55 comandos**

- Básicos (18 comandos) – listados pelo comando `hg`:
  add, annotate, clone, commit, diff, export, forget, init, log, merge, phase, pull, push, remove, serve, status, summary, update
- Avançados (37 comandos) – comandos adicionais listados pelo comando `hg help`:
  addremove, archive, backout, bisect, bookmarks, branch, branches, bundle, cat, copy, fetch, graft, grep, heads, help, identify, import, incoming, locate, manifest, outgoing, parents, paths, rebase, recover, rename, resolve, revert, rollback, root, showconfig, tag, tags, tip, unbundle, verify, version

O Git possui 144 comandos no total. Vinte um desses são os mais comumente usados segundo a lista fornecida pelo comando `git` sem parâmetros ou chaves adicionais. A lista completa dos comandos é fornecida pelo comando `git help --all`:

**git: 144 comandos**

- Comuns (21 comandos) – listados pelo comando `git`:
  add, bisect, branch, checkout, clone, commit, diff, fetch, grep, init, log, merge, mv, pull, push, rebase, reset, rm, show, status, tag
- Avançados (123 comandos) – comandos adicionais listados pelo comando `git help --all`:
  add–interactive, am, annotate, apply, archive, bisect–helper, blame, bundle, cat-file, check-attr, check-ref-format, checkout-index, cherry, cherry-pick, clean, commit-tree, config, count-objects, credential-cache, credential-cache–daemon, credential-store, daemon, describe, diff-files, diff-index, diff-tree, difftool, difftool–helper, fast-export, fast-import, fetch-pack, filter-branch, fmt-merge-msg, for-each-ref, format-patch, fsck, fsck-objects, gc, get-tar-commit-id, hash-object, help, http-backend, http-fetch,
  http-push, imap-send, index-pack, init-db, instaweb, lost-found, ls-files, ls-remote, ls-tree, mailinfo, mailsplit, merge-base, merge-file, merge-index, merge-octopus, merge-one-file, merge-ours, merge-recursive, merge-resolve, merge-subtree, merge-tree, mergetool, mktag, mktree, name-rev, notes, pack-objects, pack-redundant, pack-refs, patch-id, peek-remote, prune, prune-packed, quiltimport, read-tree, receive-pack, reflog, relink, remote, remote-ext, remote-fd, remote-ftp, remote-ftps, remote-http, remote-https, remote-testgit, repack, replace, repo-config, request-pull, rerere, rev-list, rev-parse, revert, send-pack, sh-i18n–envsubst, shell, shortlog, show-branch, show-index, show-ref, stage, stash, stripspace, submodule, symbolic-ref, tar-tree, unpack-file, unpack-objects, update-index, update-ref, update-server-info, upload-archive, upload-pack, var, verify-pack, verify-tag, web–browse, whatchanged, write-tree

O Git possui uma quantidade maior de comandos do que o Subversion e o Mercurial juntos! Isto não se deve a um maior número de funcionalidades. É apenas uma indicação de falha na integridade conceitual do projeto, que pode ser explicada em parte por razões históricas do desenvolvimento: o Git foi originalmente projetado como um mecanismo de controle de versão de baixo nível (de abstração) a partir do qual outros poderiam escrever aplicativos. No entanto, o projeto do núcleo do Git se tornou um sistema de controle de versão completo que é usado diretamente.

Melhor seria se os comandos de baixo nível tivessem sido movidos para alguma biblioteca, onde ficariam visíveis apenas aos desenvolvedores do Git, longe dos usuários finais da ferramenta.

#### Observação

Caberia aqui uma análise qualitativa sobre certos problemas de integridade conceitual do Git. Entretanto, para não misturar com as análises quantitativas sendo apresentadas,
esse aspecto será apresentado em outro momento.

Não só o número de comandos influencia no aprendizado e na operação, mas também a forma como estão organizados. O Subversion não possui o menor número de comandos, mas os organiza em categorias que facilitam muito a vida do usuário. Um desenvolvedor, por exemplo, precisaria apenas dos subcomandos do `svn` para operações de controle de versão, um administrador dos subcomandos do `svnadmin` e assim por diante.

No DVCS, o repositório é local e, por isso, todos os tipos de operação são responsabilidade do próprio desenvolvedor. Como nem sempre o nome do comando deixa clara a sua finalidade e a divisão dos comandos apenas em básicos e avançados também não acrescenta muita informação, o Mercurial e o Git deveriam usar mais categorias para classificar os comandos.

Melhor: Mercurial (menor número de comandos) e Subversion (melhor organização dos comandos)

Números de Linhas por Comando
A contagem das linhas do texto de ajuda será feita através dos seguintes comandos:

```
$ svn help <comando> | wc -l
$ hg help <comando> | wc -l
$ git help <comando> | wc -l
```

Observações:

1. Uma vez que o Git não possui tradução para o pt_BR, a comparação será feita com todos os textos em inglês.
   Para garantir que isto aconteça, é necessário ajustar a variável de ambiente `LANGUAGE`:

   ```
   $ export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
   ```
2. Como alguns comandos do Git executam várias funcionalidades diferentes, alguns textos de ajuda serão agregados para manter o equilíbrio da comparação.
   Por exemplo, o texto de ajuda do comando `git checkout` será comparado com o agrupamento dos textos de ajuda dos comandos `update`, `branch` e `revert` do Mercurial:

   ```
   $ (hg help update && hg help branch && hg help revert) | wc -l
   ```
3. Alguns comandos do Subversion, Mercurial e Git possuem o mesmo nome mas executam operações total ou parcialmente diferentes como, por exemplo, o comando `add` e o comando `revert`. Apesar disto, serão tratados como equivalentes.
4. Comandos tais como `push` e `pull` não existem no Subversion.
   Nestes casos, o número contabilizado de linhas é zero.
5. O número de linhas do texto de ajuda do Git varia conforme a largura do terminal. A análise apresentada usou uma largura de 80 colunas para as medições.
   A tabela a seguir mostra os dados coletados a partir da execução do [scriptcomparativo_help_svn_hg_git.py](http://www.pronus.eng.br/download/comparativo_help_svn_hg_git.py): a tabela pode ser vista nesse [link](http://pronus.eng.br/blog/http:/pronus.eng.br/blog/comparacao-entre-subversion-mercurial-e-git-parte-2).

A representação gráfica dos resultados é mostrada a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O Git possui textos mais longos em todos os casos, o que indica seus comandos são mais difíceis de serem explicados.

O Subversion teve um total de linhas de texto maior que o Mercurial, mesmo com menos comandos sendo analisados. O responsável foi o comando `svn merge`, que é reconhecidamente complexo no Subversion e cujo texto de ajuda corresponde sozinho a mais de um terço do total. Isto reforça a premissa de que quanto mais complexo o comando, maior o número de linhas de texto de ajuda correspondente.

O Mercurial se saiu melhor tanto no quadro geral quanto em todos os comandos equivalentes ao Subversion. Pela lógica utilizada, os comandos do Mercurial são mais simples dos que os do Git e até mesmo do que os comandos do Subversion.

Melhor: Mercurial

Conclusão

Os números coletados indicam que o Git é mais complexo que o Subversion e o Mercurial, o que era esperado conforme já relatado em várias análises disponíveis na internet ([1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control), [2](http://pronus.eng.br/blog/http:/pronus.eng.br/blog/comparacao-entre-subversion-mercurial-e-git-parte-1), [3](http://blog.vandersonguidi.com.br/utilidade-publica/qual-o-melhor-controle-de-versao-subversiongitmercurial), [4](http://www.pronus.eng.br/download/comparativo_help_svn_hg_git.py)).

Fonte: [Link](http://pronus.eng.br/blog/http:/pronus.eng.br/blog/comparacao-entre-subversion-mercurial-e-git-parte-2)

Answer (score -1):

Por concepção o git é mais rápido em sistemas operacionais Linux em contra partida o suporte  à windows é limitado e em resumo ele é mais flexível e poderoso. Por outro lado o mercurial é mais simples e fácil de aprender, portanto a curva de aprendizagem é menor.

O git tem uma documentação incrível, toda online e em várias linguagens e tem aperfeiçoado em questão de simplicidade. Mas dizem que a documentação do mercurial também é ótima.

Eu recomendo o git por ter uma comunidade maior, por ser mais rápido em operações que precisam de comunicar com a rede, por ter mais opções de serviços de hospedagem de código (como bitbucket, github e gitorious), por ser mais completo (tem opções de comando disponível mas isso aumento um pouco em complexidade).

Você pode saber mais sobre a diferenças entre eles por [aqui](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2012/03/git-vs-mercurial-why-git/) e [aqui](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2012/02/mercurial-vs-git-why-mercurial/).

Comment: Acredito que não seja interessante citar sites externos, pois os mesmos podem ficar offline e sua resposta não seria mais válida, temos que pensar que a resposta dure para sempre.

Comment: Não entendi qual foi o propósito do seu comentário?

Comment: Propósito é não ter link externos em respostas dos quais é a parte mais importante da sua resposta, por que o resto você defende o git e não mostra realmente as diferenças como a resposta do @Geilton Xavier

Comment: Entendi. A resposta acima é muito boa e completa, mas sinceramente acredito que em fóruns devemos apresentar respostas claras e objetivas, não necessariamente auto contidas, por ser cansativo.

Por exemplo poderíamos ter 50 respostas nesta página, seria altamente cansativo ler toda a resposta acima, sendo muito mais interessante ler a explicação completa em uma página externa.

Mas obrigado pela dica.